# Yandex map как отключить вывод "возможных" адресов

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Сейчас при попытке вывода несуществующего адреса, карта автоматически сама выставляет маркеры на "возможные" адреса. 
Как возможно это отключить? 
В справочнике yandex api не нашел.
Версия api-yandex 2.1

```
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [43.1056200, 131.8735300],
        zoom: 9
    });

    var objects = ymaps.geocode("Владивосток, ул. Васильева, 45");

    objects.then(
        function (res) {
            myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Что вы ожидаете от результата геокодирования, намеренно делая запрос для несуществующего адреса? Ограничить выдачу геокодирования можно указав параметр results=1.
Пример из документации: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode

Comment: Суть в том, что пользователь может "криво" ввести адрес не посмотрев и в итоге на карте отображается не верная информация, чего собственно и хотелось бы избежать.
Уж лучше пусть карта будет пустая, чем показывать неверные маркеры.

Comment: Вы можете ограничить поиск указанной областью или уточнять найденный адрес у пользователя. API не может знать, верный или неверный адрес вводит пользователь - можно ошибиться набрав номер дома 3 вместо 2, и тут нет ошибки, а маркер будет в другом месте. Потому возвращается несколько подходящих результатов с учетом возможным опечаток. Вы можете проводить проверку результатов на своей стороне в зависимости от условий поиска. У API есть методы для обработки результатов: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geocoding/searchControl-docpage/